# Some Twilio Pages are all Emojis and Gibberish

Tags: twilio

While navigating through the Twilio website, some pages are unreadable.  Letters are replaced with emojis and gibberish - while other pages are fine.  I checked to see if I'm missing a font or something but it doesn't seem so.  Anyone else see this issue and solve it?  Thanks!

[screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPMhg.png)

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Can you check in dev tools on a page like that and see what font has been selected (Firefox can do this, I'm not sure about Chrome)?

Comment: font-family: Inter,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: #0263e0 0 0 0 1px;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 margin: 0 0 17px 0;  

Most of these fonts are available and none of them are wing-ding-ish or icon fonts, so I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Hey, so that's the full CSS rule, but can you tell me what the used font is. This is how I would find it in Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz1eH.png. Also, what browser and OS are you experiencing this in?

Comment: Hi @philnash thank you for helping me think about CSS and fonts.  It turns out that the very first font listed "Inter" which is a popular Google Font, has a ding-batty doppelganger with the exact same name!   I had Inter.TTF loaded in my fonts library and when my browser tripped over the Inter family in Twilio's CSS rule, chaos ensued.   Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Oh that is weird! Glad you got it figured out! And the console team at Twilio will be happy to know they haven’t accidentally snuck dingbats into the front end 

Comment: I am relieved too, I thought it was something much more serious.  Twilio team is so courteous and genuinely interested I was very impressed.  Thanks again @philnash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t turns out that the very first font listed "Inter" which is a popular Google Font, has a ding-batty doppelganger with the exact same name! I had Inter.TTF loaded in my fonts library and when my browser tripped over the Inter family in Twilio's CSS rule, chaos ensued. Thanks again @philnash for your help!